# How do I find an irrational root of a quartic function?

Tags: functions, roots, quadratics, irrational-numbers

For example, the equation $2x^4 - 3x^3 - 1 = 0$ has no rational roots, but it does have an irrational root between x = 1 and x = 2. If it had a rational root, I would be able to find it, but I am a bit confused on how to find an irrational root.

Comment: Right, this root is approximately $x=1.61803398875$. You could use the formulas for [quartic equations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuarticEquation.html).

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case consider: 
\begin{align}
2 \, x^4 - 3 \, x^3 -1 &= (a \, x^2 + b \, x + 1)(x^2 + c \, x -1) \\
&= a \, x^4 + (ac + b) \, x^3 + (-a + bc + 1) \, x^2 + (-b + c) \, x - 1 
\end{align}
This leads to $b = c$, $a=2$, $1 - a + bc = -1 + b^2 = 0$ or $b = \pm 1$, and
$ac + b = 3b = -3$ which narrows $b$ to $b = -1$. Now,
$$2 \, x^4 - 3 \, x^3 -1 = (a \, x^2 + b \, x + 1)(x^2 + c \, x -1) = (2 \, x^2 - x +1)(x^2 - x - 1).$$
The polynomial $2 \, x^2 - x + 1$ can be factored as $2(x - a)(x - b)$, where $4a = 1 + i \, \sqrt{7}$ and $4b = 1 - i \sqrt{7}$, and $x^2 - x - 1$ can be factored as $(x - \alpha)(x - \beta)$ where $2 \, \alpha = 1 + \sqrt{5}$ and $2 \, \beta = 1 - \sqrt{5}$. This brings the factorization into the form:
$$2 \, x^4 - 3 \, x^3 -1 = 2(x - a)(x - b)(x - \alpha)(x - \beta).$$
The four roots would then be
$$x \in \{ a, b, \alpha, \beta \} = \left\{ \frac{1 + i \, \sqrt{7}}{4}, \frac{1 - i \, \sqrt{7}}{4}, \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}, \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}  \right\}.$$

Comment: did you use the quadratic formula to figure out what α and β are?

Comment: @MunizaSiddiqui For a quadratic equation it is sometimes easier to find the roots and then make the factorization. In another view the polynomial $x^2 - x - 1$ is connected with finding the solution to the Fibonacci and Lucas number difference equation. This is where the notation of $\alpha, \beta$ are most often used.

Answer (score 1):

$$ -1 - 3x^3 + 2x^4 = (-1-x+x^2)(1-x+2x^2)
$$
Can you continue from here?